# Flutter: The method '[]' was called on null. StreamProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a StreamProvider reading from Firebase Firestore which works fine when there is data in the document, but if there isn't a document/collection created yet, i get the error "The method '[]' was called on null." It is just reading a number from firestore, if there is null i want to default to 0.

I have tried using the "initialdata" property of SteamProvider, setting to 0, but not sure if i set it up right. I am thinking the "catchError" property of StreamProvider may work, but I can't find any examples online.

See below for the StreamProvider, its under a MultiProvider. Below that is the PomosWeekly class, it's just reading an int.

```
StreamProvider<PomosWeekly>.value(
            stream: Global.pomosWeeklyRef.documentStream2,
            initialData: PomosWeekly.initialData()),
```

```
class PomosWeekly {
  int count;

  PomosWeekly({this.count});

  factory PomosWeekly.fromMap(Map data) {
    return PomosWeekly(
      count: data['week'] ??
          0,
    );
  }

  factory PomosWeekly.initialData() {
    return PomosWeekly(
      count: 0,
    );
  }
}
```

The stream works fine if there is documents/fields in that location, but errors if the document hasn't been created yet, I just want to return 0 if there is an error. Error is "The method '[]' was called on null."

Comment: try `data.containsKey('week') ? data['week'] : 0`

Comment: It looks like `data` is `null`

Comment: Tried data.containsKey('week') ? data['week'] : 0, no good.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, I hope it might give you some insight as in how you can approach the problem. Initially, my code looked like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final docre = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context);
    String docStr = '';
    if(docre != null){
      docStr = docre.data['docid'];
    } else {
      docStr = 'noData';
    }

    return MyStreamWidget();
}
```

After that, I was getting exactly same error as you, I tweaked the code over and over and did the following:
1. Had the code in a try catch block where I am using `docre`.
2. Tweaked the return statement with an if-else.

Here is the tweaked code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final docre = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context);
    String docStr = '';
    try{
      docStr = docre.data['docid'];
    }catch(e){
    }

    return docStr != '' ? MyStreamWidget() : Text('');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This uses exception handling for control flow which is a bad practice not only because it complicates the code but it is also not performant.